External drive no longer boots an old MacBook after running it on newer iMac
I installed macOS on an external drive to use it on my 2015 MacBook Pro 15" and then used the same drive on an iMac 2017. Now, it only boots on the iMac.
I am sure the OS updated when I used it on the iMac. Does anyone know how to make it work again on the laptop?

Is the OS now installed on the external drive compatible with the 2015 laptop?  A 2017 iMac can run Ventura, a 2015 MBP stops at Monterey.
